# How to get the total for all user that have register

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problem.  I only have an idea on how to display number of staff and student that have been register in the different table database. But I did not know how to sum up the number of staff and student that have been register.

This is a code to display number of staff

```
<?php
  $s = "SELECT * FROM multiusers_staff";
  $sresult = $con->query($s);
  $scount  = mysqli_num_rows($sresult);
?>
<h3><?php echo $scount;?></h3>
<p>Staff </p>
```

But when I insert this code, its not working for sum up number of staff and student. Can anyone help.

```
<?php 
  $t = "SELECT * FROM multiusers_staff and mulitusers_student";
  $tresult = $con->query($t);
  $tcount  = mysqli_num_rows($tresult);
?>
<h3><?php echo $tcount;?></h3>
<p> Totals User</p>
```

Comment: Please share your table details

Comment: Does each table have the same columns? You can do a `UNION` -> `SELECT * FROM multiusers_staff UNION SELECT * FROM mulitusers_student` - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: each table have same columns. The table for student consists student_id, student_email, student_username and student_password. And table for staff also have staff_id, staff_email, staff_username and staff_password @MdMonjurUlHasan

Comment: You can use keyword COUNT to count. And you need to use JOIN when you want two or more different table but the join table must be based on a related column between them.

Comment: 1. Use count(*). 2. Use asingle table for all users

Comment: @DayaaMohdJohan which column in both tables is related each other? if related can use JOIN syntax. If not can use UNION syntax.

Comment: not related to each other. how can I use UNION syntax ? sorry because this is new for me @SalehinRafi

Comment: @Sean already pointed it out. But I think you better look at the answer below. count by each table is more clean and easy way to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that can help you:

```html
 <?PHP
    include 'config.php';
    $result = $link->query("SELECT student FROM tableofstudent");
$result2 = $link->query("SELECT teacher FROM tableofteacher");
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $row_cnt2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
    echo $row_cnt + $row_cnt2;
```

Hope it helps you.
Warm Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two queries or one queries with sub query for solving this. The easiest way is to use two queries. (Technically this is not the best solution though)

```
<?php
$s = "SELECT * FROM multiusers_staff";
$sresult = $con->query($s);
$scount  = mysqli_num_rows($sresult);

$s = "SELECT * FROM multiusers_student";
$sresult = $con->query($s);
$scount1 = mysqli_num_rows($sresult);

$scount += $scount1;
?>
<h3><?php echo $scount;?></h3>
<p>Staff and student </p>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the helping me. The problem solved!

Comment: You are welcome. Please help the future readers by upvoting and accepting the answer in here.